# jsTree not working

Tags: jquery, html, jstree

I am new to jQuery and jsTree and I am not sure why I can't get it working?
Using this tutorial:
http://tkgospodinov.com/jstree-part-1-introduction/

And this html / javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <title>
            BLA BLA
        </title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!--
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">                                         
        $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#selector").jstree();
        });                                     
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="selector">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Team A's Projects</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a>Iteration 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>Story A</a></li>
                                <li><a>Story B</a></li>
                                <li><a>Story C</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        <li><a>Iteration 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Story D</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Nothing seems to work.
I get the following error:

```
$("#selector").jstree is not a function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working demo of your example: [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/ak4Ed/) and [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/J5ZaK/2/)

Please check the reference and how you are calling it. This tree should be exactly the same as what you are looking for.

Rest the source of all the documentation can be found here: http://www.jstree.com/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
```

Include the files mentioned below. See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/J5ZaK/2/).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did as you have in the example and now I get:
ncaught exception: jsTree hotkeys: jQuery hotkeys plugin not included.

Comment: Hiya @ArthurWulfWhite check the answer above you were missing hotkey.js `<script type='text/javascript' src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
` include you can copy paste the links from above. **Updated another jsfiddle from scratch with external files sorces** http://jsfiddle.net/J5ZaK/2/ let me know how it goes :) cheers!

Comment: Thanks again Tats, this works great! how did you find the static links?

Comment: No worries @ArthurWulfWhite Glad it helped, `MAGIC` lol kidding, I went to the jstree documentation did view source on one of the demo and got the sources. :) Have nice one, cheerios

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your browser just isn't loading jstree.js properly?

You can try loading jstree.js from CDN (content delivery network) just like jquery is being loaded by changing the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cachedcommons.org/cache/jquery-jstree/1.0.0/javascripts/jquery-jstree-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes! This seems to work but now I get a weird looking tree. :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code can't access to the function `jstree()`. Maybe something is wrong on the path to jstree.js?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's the weird thing, I checked that five times before posting.. the file is in the same directory as the html.. and I copy pasted the file name so it should be right.